# TypeORM insert doesn't work with big number

Tags: node.js, oracle, typeorm

I'm using TypeORM in a project and I'm facing an issue I've never seen before.

I'm sending an object with some values from my Postman to my back-end API. For example: `{ n1: 999, n2: 999 }`.
Everything was working fine till last wednesday when the front-end sent a longer number: 9999999999.

What's happening now is that the request is kept pending since the object is not being inserted in the database.
The command that is keeping the request pending is the below one:

```
const result = await this.myRepo.insert(myObject);
```

myObject is a TypeORM Entity.

It doesn't throw any errors nor anything and this insert command is not a big deal. It's a simple insert.

Running some tests, I figured out that numbers till 5555555555 (5 billions) are inserted but numbers above this, it just doesn't work. The database (Oracle) indeed accepts these long numbers. The prove of it is that I'm able to insert 9999999999 (9 billions) in a raw SQL command (it's why I think maybe is something to do with TypeORM)

Anyone has any idea what's going on? Any tip where I can keep looking for answers? We are out of ideas.

EDIT 1: I changed the method above by the one below:

```
 const insertStatement = this
  .sauFtPagamentoBaseRepository
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .insert()
  .into(SauFtPagamentoBase)
  .values([pagamentoBase]);
```

Doing so I was able to call this:

```
const queryAndParameters = insertStatement.getQueryAndParameters();
```

The log of the queryAndParameters is the insert script generated by TypeORM. I tried to run the script in my DBeaver by just copying and pasting and it ran succesfully.

EDIT 2: I let the pending request end. It shows a "Segmentation fault" message in the console (I have no idea what this means but I'm looking for in the internet)

Comment: Work out what each layer is passing to the next.  What is being passed to node-oracledb (which I expect you're using)?  What is node-oracledb passing to the DB, if anything?  If you don't have a debugger, add some console.log() dumping in various files.  Also see https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#tracingsql

Comment: Hello @ChristopherJones, thanks for your answer!
I'm tracing the object using logs in each layer (you can see the log here: [link]https://github.com/FilipeVeber/stackoverflow-question/blob/main/logs.txt
We'are using the following oracle lib in all our microservices: [link]https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracledb
Thank you for the link! I'll read to see if I can find anything that helps.

Comment: @CristopherJones I edited the post with some tests I have runned. Hope it helps in any way. I'm wondering if maybe has something to do with a library-versions-combination problem among Node, oracledb and typeorm. I updated each of them to the their last version to run more tests. I don't know. I'm really out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

We figured out the issue. Instead of passing the values as integer, we have to pass them as string because a sort of a translation from TypeORM to the oracle db layer.